# Circular motion lift

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Consider a particle of mass $m$ attached to a massless string (fixed at one end) in a lift going down with acceleration $g$. What minimum velocity $v_0$ should be given to it so that it performs complete circular motion?

Since it is going with an acceleration $a$ downwards the tension in the string is 0, so will it regain tension when given velocity or will it never do circular motion?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the lift is going down with a constant acceleration g,  pseudo force $F_{Pseudo} = mg$ acts on the particle(direction opposite to acceleration of lift - upward) when analyzing the situation w.r.t the lift which is a non inertial frame of reference. This force cancels the gravitation force $mg$ acting on the particle on the downward direction

Currently, there is no external force acting on the particle.

> What minimum velocity $v_0$ should be given to it so that it performs complete circular motion?

Since there are no external forces, the situation can be comparable to that of a horizontal plane. The particle does uniform circular motion when it is given any non zero velocity as there are no tangential forces acting on the particle.

Yes. the string will "regain" its tension and the particle does uniform circular motion